# Adding a Combobox To a Datatable as one of its column and bind this datatable to datatgrid

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have created a combobox column in `datattable` by name table as below

```
table.Columns.Add("Signals", typeof(ComboBox));
```

I have A Combobox:

```
ComboBox cmbBox = new ComboBox();
```

now to this combobox i am adding items that are read from a list of strings:

```
foreach (ObjectItem item in objClsSignal.lstTerminalLevel1)
{
cmbBox.Items.Add(item.FullName);

}
```

`lstTerminalLevel1` is a list of `Objectitems` and from this objectitem i am reading the name of object and adding it to the combobox.
then i am adding that combobox as a new row to the data table `"table"`

```
table.Rows.Add(cmbBox);
```

them i am biunding the datatable to datagrid as below  :

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

The output that i am getting is :

```
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox Items.Count:2
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox Items.Count:1
```

so on... but what i want is the contents stored in the combobox..

Any idea on how to go about??

Comment: This is not WinForms. In WPF, we don't put UI objects into a `DataTable`... in fact, we rarely even use `DataTable`s at all. I suggest that you read the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx) page on MSDN to get a better idea.

Comment: If you want to store the contents of the combobox, store the contents and not the ComboBox.

Answer (score 3):

WPF has separate UI and Data Layers.

When you write

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

What it is saying is

> For each DataGridRow in table.DefaultView, create a `<DataGridRow>`
>   in the `dataGrid1` and set the `DataContext` behind that row to the
>   `DataRow` object

So what gets rendered is

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataRow DataContext=table[0] />
    <DataRow DataContext=table[1] />
</DataGrid>
```

If you didn't tell the DataGrid to draw it's rows in any specific way, it will use the default which is to create a Column for each property in the `DataContext` object, and each cell will be a `TextBlock` with the `.Text` property displaying the `.ToString()` of each value.

So what you are seeing is

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataRow DataContext=table[0]>
        <DataGridCell>
            <TextBlock Text=table[0].ToString() />
        </DataGridCell>
    </DataRow>
    <DataRow DataContext=table[1]>
        <DataGridCell>
            <TextBlock Text=table[1].ToString() />
        </DataGridCell>
    </DataRow>
</DataGrid>
```

If you want to display a ComboBox there, you need to tell the DataGrid how to draw that cell. For example,

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>           
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItem="{Binding }" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now it will render like this :

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataRow DataContext=table[0]>
        <DataGridCell>
            <ComboBox SelectedItem=table[0] />
        </DataGridCell>
    </DataRow>
    <DataRow DataContext=table[1]>
        <DataGridCell>
            <ComboBox SelectedItem=table[1] />
        </DataGridCell>
    </DataRow>
</DataGrid>
```

Of course, you'll also want to set the ItemsSource property of the ComboBox so it has values to select from. At this point, I'd say just scrap what you're doing and build it properly for WPF.

Create a class to hold the data of each item being displayed in the Grid

```
public class MyObject()
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Create a `ViewModel` containing a `ObservableCollection<MyObject>` for the grid's data, and a separate `ObservableCollection<string>` for the ComboBox item data.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyGridData { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> AllNames { get; set; }
}
```

(I'm using `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` because it will automatically update the UI when items are added or removed from the collection)

Populate `MyViewModel` with your data

```
var vm = new MyViewModel();
vm.MyGridData = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
vm.AllNames = new ObservableCollection<string>();

foreach (ObjectItem item in objClsSignal.lstTerminalLevel1)
{
    vm.MyGridData.Add(new MyObject() { FullName = item.FullName });
    if (!vm.AllNames.Contains(item.FullName))
        vm.AllNames.Add(item.FullName);
}
```

Set (or Bind) your DataGrid's DataContext

```
dataGrid1.DataContext = vm;
```

And set it up for how to draw each item

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>           
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItem="{Binding FullName}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1, Path=DataContext.AllNames}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

What gets rendered is this :

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataRow DataContext=MyGridData[0]>
        <DataGridCell>
            <ComboBox SelectedItem=MyGridData[0].FullName
                      ItemsSource=vm.AllNames />
        </DataGridCell>
    </DataRow>
    <DataRow DataContext=MyGridData[1]>
        <DataGridCell>
            <ComboBox SelectedItem=MyGridData[1].FullName
                      ItemsSource=vm.AllNames />
        </DataGridCell>
    </DataRow>
</DataGrid>
```